# Using VLookup to create a functional DATE() format output

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here is the deal, I am dealing with some really shoddy output, and no I can't correct this... it's not my data.  I just have to work with it.

Here is what I want to do, because this needs to kill two birds with one stone.

I need to use VLookup to look up a ticket, once it looks up the ticket it needs to output a date. The date though is stuck between a universal "date" string...

```
2019-06-10T17:20:28+00:00
```

This string is in tab Ticket_Import in row O.

Now, I need to translate to a date that can be later sifted through and put into a chart.  The only way I can figure out to do this is using DATE()

Now, here is my problem. I have figured out how to do it...mostly.  I am just getting the wrong date back in return, I think it's skipping the data and just saying "Good luck jr." in it's own way...

Here is my formula:

```
=XLOOKUP(A1261,Ticket_Import!B:B,DATE(LEFT(Ticket_Import!O:O,4),MID(Ticket_Import!O:O,6,2),MID(Ticket_Import!O:O,8,2)),"Empty")
```

Now, I took this one specifically because I need the date to show up so it will be searchable, which I am not even sure if this will work or not.

The XLOOKUP is searching for the number in A1261, which is 2690.

2690's O row output is

```
2019-06-10T17:20:28+00:00
```

Now, when I use this script I wrote it shows as an end result 2019-12-31 instead of 2019-06-10

Which is telling me it can't output properly...

Can someone help me out with this and explain or show me how to get this actually working properly?

Like I said, I can't edit the raw data, but I can make the data output be whatever it needs to be to make this work... as long as **I** can understand it and reproduce it, because I have to do this over 4,000 more times...

Realistically, once this is done I am going to be copying and pasting the output anyway through a VBA script so that this will not be such a resource hog in the future.  I am playing catch up to something that needed to be done ages ago...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it...! (YAY ME!)

Ok, I know immature, but this was causing me no end of grief...

The proper code is:

```
=XLOOKUP(A1261,Ticket_Import!B:B,DATE(LEFT(Ticket_Import!O:O,4),MID(Ticket_Import!O:O,6,2),MID(Ticket_Import!O:O,9,2)),"Empty")
```

I had an improper mid alignment for the day.

Thanks for everyone that had a chance to look at and and scratch their heads for a minute or two... either way, This is also good for people to use later if they need to make it work for them as well!

Comment: Just curious but what would `=DATEVALUE(LEFT(Ticket_Import!O:O,10))` return in your case?

Comment: @JvdV It shows as written, the first four characters left of where it's meant to be looking.